# When importing a csv into Excel(2016) is there a way to specify which data should be column headers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv

I have a csv file

```
user1,Donated,460
user1,GiftedT1,137
user1,GiftedT2,205
user1,GiftedT3,144
user1,Cards,123
user2,GiftedT2,123
user2,Donated,123
user2,Cards,123
```

Is there a way when importing the csv to Excel, I can say "use the data in the 2nd comma field as a column header"

I want `Donated`,`GiftedT1`,`GiftedT2`,`GiftedT3`,`Cards` to be used as column headers, then put username on the left column and populate each column with the data accordingly.

**Formatted like this**
[image: Formatted like this]

Comment: Import as-is into 3 columns then build pivot table of needed form.

Comment: ^ That, or use VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- `Data => Get&Transform => from Text/CSV`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the **File Path** in Line 2 of the code
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the **File Path** in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm.

  - Also take a look at Microsoft Help for the functions

**M Code**

```
let
//import the file
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\data.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=3, 
        Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Column1", type text}, 
        {"Column2", type text}, 
        {"Column3", Int64.Type}
    }),

//Pivot on Column2 with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", 
        List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Column2]), "Column2", "Column3")
        
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]